# Getting "Run-time error '-2147024864 (80070020) which saving outlook attachment on arrival

Tags: vba, outlook

I run below script to save Outlook attachment on arrival of email. But I frequently get Run-time error '-2147024864 (80070020), which will always stop the inflow of Outlook email. Please advise how to get rid.

```
Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "C:\Email\"

     For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments

          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName

          Set objAtt = Nothing
     Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Could someone please provide their input.

Comment: You have save folder as "C:\Email\" but your adding a second slash later: your SaveAsFile is therefore: "C:\Email\\foo.***" Use objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & objAtt.DisplayName

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will try this now.

Comment: If I am saving like C:\Email\Report. Will it work?

Comment: click the "debug" button on the popup dialog.  the code window should show up, with the failed line highlighted in yellow.  move the mouse pointer over the objAtt.DisplayName and you should see a tip popup that shows the value of the item under the mouse pointer.  hopefully that helps you determine the cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code please

it prints the name of each attachment before it saves the attachment

press ctrl-G to see "immediate window" where the printout is sent

check the last file name printed when the program crashes

it may provide some insight

```
Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    saveFolder = "C:\Email\"

    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments

        debug.print objAtt.DisplayName        ' print attachment name to "immediate window"

        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName

    Next
    Set objAtt = Nothing
End Sub
```