# Cannot Save Outlook File Attachment

Tags: vba

I have an Outlook rule that searches messages for a particular attachment, and then saves the attachment using the VBA script below. It had been running successfully for over a year, but has been failing recently and returning the following error:

> Run-time error '-2147024864 (80070020)': Cannot save the attachment.

Here is the script:

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "c:\temp\"
     For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\inventory.csv"
          Set objAtt = Nothing
     Next
End Sub
```

When I run debug it points to this line as the source of the problem:

```
objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\inventory.csv"
```

The objAtt item is named searchresults.csv in the email message and appears to be properly defined when it hits the VBA script. I can't see anything else that might be wrong with this line, and as mentioned, it worked just fine for over year up to this point.

Does anyone know why this script would now be breaking and how I might resolve it?

Although this issue is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44621280/getting-run-time-error-2147024864-80070020-which-saving-outlook-attachment), I did not find a solution there.

Comment: Protip: when something like this fails, put a breakpoint (F9) and inspect your variables. Here a breakpoint on the line you identified, and then `?saveFolder & "\inventory.csv"` in the *immediate pane* (Ctrl+G) would have found the problem.

Comment: And I hope your real code differs from what you posted -- if you have multiple attachments -- because you are saving them all to the same file name.

Comment: Thanks Wayne. Only one attachment per message. Saving them each day with the same file name allows a simple FTP routine to grab the file and place it on a customer's server each day.

Answer (score 5):

You doubled up on your backslashes. Either include it at the end of your path or the beginning of your filename, not both places. I'm going to assume you are already positive that `C:\temp` actually exists.

Comment: I noticed the double backslashes, but for some reason, the script was working fine up to this point, even with them. Also, the same script runs for a different file name, and that script is still working without issue. Hence the source of my confusion. c:\temp does exist.

Comment: And you still have a `C:\temp` folder existing? Are there multiple attachments? Does the file already exist?

Comment: Yes, c:\temp exists. It shows that the other identical script (except for the file name it uses) uploaded successfully today, as the file date updated to today's date. But this one, for the file named searchresults.csv failed and returned the "cannot save attachment" error.

Comment: Only one attachment. The file is attached to an email, and this script has been saving the file to disk. I can't figure out what's changed.

Comment: If you try to save it manually with the same name and in the same place, what happens? Does it work then?